# Setting a index in the code for Logstash / Kibana in Java

Tags: java, logstash, kibana

We are setting some data for our logging in our code.
We use Logstash for grabbing the data and Kibana visualization.

```
log.info("LogData Object::::::{}", StructuredArguments.keyValue("LogData", data));
```

The problem is, that we can't filter in Kibana for it.
[image]

When I looked into the documentation of [StructuredArguments](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder/blob/master/src/main/java/net/logstash/logback/argument/StructuredArguments.java), I could not find any way to index it.
I can't also set the index in the settings, the field is not there.

Is there any way to do it on Java level?

Comment: Have you tried to refresh your field list for that index pattern in Kibana? Go to Management, Kibana, Index Patterns, Select your index pattern and click in refresh field list.

Comment: Hey @leandrojmp, that was enough to solve the problem. Thanks a lot. If you want to write it as an answer, I can check it as a correct.

Comment: Ok, it is done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refresh the field list to let Kibana knows about the mapping of that field.

Just go in `Management` > `Kibana` > `Index Patterns`, select your index pattern and click on the refresh field list icon on the right.